# Problem when get int data from TextController or API in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to get int data entered in the `TextField()` in flutter, I'm using `TextEditingController` like this:

```
TextEditingController _section_id = new TextEditingController();
```

and using this controller in it:

```
TextField(controller: _section_id,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,)
```

and I get int data in this way:

```
Repository().placeAddApiProvider(int.parse(_section_id.text));
```

but it shows me an error:

```
E/flutter (25586): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid number (at character 1)
E/flutter (25586): 
E/flutter (25586): ^
E/flutter (25586): 
E/flutter (25586): #0      int._throwFormatException (dart:core/runtime/libintegers_patch.dart:129:7)
E/flutter (25586): #1      int.parse (dart:core/runtime/libintegers_patch.dart:53:14)
E/flutter (25586): #2      AddPlaceState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:mosul/src/ui/users/add_place.dart:93:37)
E/flutter (25586): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25586): #3      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:513:14)
E/flutter (25586): #4      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:568:30)
E/flutter (25586): #5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:120:24)
E/flutter (25586): #6      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:242:9)
E/flutter (25586): #7      TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:204:7)
E/flutter (25586): #8      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
E/flutter (25586): #9      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:218:20)
E/flutter (25586): #10     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:192:22)
E/flutter (25586): #11     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:149:7)
E/flutter (25586): #12     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:101:7)
E/flutter (25586): #13     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:85:7)
E/flutter (25586): #14     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1136:13)
E/flutter (25586): #15     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
E/flutter (25586): #16     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:931:7)
E/flutter (25586): #17     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:223:10)
E/flutter (25586): #18     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:144:5)
E/flutter (25586): 
V/ActivityThread(25586): updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{1e7c9680 token=android.os.BinderProxy@2565abb2 {org.codeforiraq.mosul/org.codeforiraq.mosul.MainActivity}} show : false
E/OpenGLRenderer(25586): SFEffectCache:clear(), mSize = 0
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25586): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

There is no problem in (`Repository().placeAddApiProvider`), and data return from API for `section_id` is int, I tried in postman and everything worked well.

Comment: you have to add some validation logic to your function. the initial value of _section_id.text is an empty string that will produce a FormatException use tryParse instead or just add validation logic to your placeAddApiProvider function

Answer (score 0):

The initial value of your `TextField` is just an empty string. Trying to parse that into an `int` will produce a `FormatException` error.

You may want to rewrite your code like this:

```dart
if (_section_id.text.trim() != "") {
Repository().placeAddApiProvider(int.parse(_section_id.text.trim()));
}
```

Comment: i do this, but the code inside (if statement) not implement, because it is always equal " " or null, Why?

Comment: Are you initializing the `TextEditingController` inside the `initState()` method? It's the recommended way. And as for why it's equal "" or null, you'll have to show us some more codes. Like, where you are initializing the controller, where you are calling `_section_id.text` and such.  @OsamaMohammed

Answer (score -1):

I wrote below code but I could not get user typing text

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late final PageManager _pageManager;
  final TextEditingController _youtubeUrl = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    String youtubeUrl =
        'https://cdns-preview-d.dzcdn.net/stream/${_youtubeUrl.text}.mp3';
    _pageManager = PageManager(youtubeUrl);
  }
```

but when user insert text in textfield it doesent paste into _youtubeUrl.text

```
 child: TextField(
           controller: _youtubeUrl,
           style: const TextStyle(
             color: Color.fromRGBO(132, 102, 158, 1),
             fontSize: 13.0,
        ),)
```

but when you link directly player it works very well. could you help me to fix it ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]